# JavaFX extending Graphs

Tags: java, javafx

How do i plot the straight **line of best fit** and the **product-moment correlation coefficient** on a Scatter diagram using JavaFX library? I've tried to Google a few examples but none were precise or even similar to what i'm trying to do. I'm new to JavaFX so any help is appreciated. There were a few examples on the internet but all were for completely different libraries which is of no help to me.

I have the following code which displays a Scatter diagram (just an example):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Scatter extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 100, 20);
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 100, 20);        
        final ScatterChart<Number,Number> sc = new
            ScatterChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        xAxis.setLabel("Average across all exams");                
        yAxis.setLabel("Spring Term test marks");
        sc.setTitle("Students marks");

        XYChart.Series plots = new XYChart.Series();
        plots.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10,15));
        plots.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(15,20));
        plots.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(77,77));
        plots.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(55,13));
        plots.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(44,22));
        plots.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(45,43));

        sc.getData().add(plots);
        Scene scene  = new Scene(sc, 600, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual formulae computation of the line of best fit and the correlation coefficient can be easily found elsewhere (and sound a bit like a homework problem), so I will omit those; it sounds like you just want to know how to add nodes (e.g. the actual line) to the chart.

The basic idea is to subclass `ScatterChart` and override the `layoutPlotChildren` method. You can use CSS to color each best fit line the same color as the data in the corresponding series by referencing the looked-up-colors `CHART_COLOR_N` for `N=1...8`.

Here is an example (I just use dummy values for the formula for the line, you can replace with the real calculations):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class ScatterPlotWithBestFitLine extends ScatterChart<Number, Number> {

    private final NumberAxis xAxis ;
    private final NumberAxis yAxis ;

    private final List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();


    public ScatterPlotWithBestFitLine(NumberAxis xAxis, NumberAxis yAxis) {
        super(xAxis, yAxis);
        this.xAxis = xAxis ;
        this.yAxis = yAxis ;

        getStylesheets().add("best-fit-line.css");
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutPlotChildren() {

        getPlotChildren().removeAll(lines);
        lines.clear();

        super.layoutPlotChildren();

        int index = 0 ;
        for (Series<Number, Number> series : getData()) {

            Line line = new Line();
            line.setStartX(xAxis.getDisplayPosition(xAxis.getLowerBound()));
            line.setEndX(xAxis.getDisplayPosition(xAxis.getUpperBound()));

            int count = (index % 8) + 1 ;
            line.getStyleClass().add("best-fit-line");
            line.getStyleClass().add("best-fit-line-"+count);

            // TODO compute actual line of best fit...
            // can iterate through values with:

            // for (Data<Number, Number> d : series.getData()) {
            //     double x = d.getXValue().doubleValue();
            //     double y = d.getYValue().doubleValue();
            // }

            // just dummy values:
            double m = 0 ;
            double b = (getData().size() - index) * yAxis.getLowerBound() + (index + 1) * yAxis.getUpperBound() / 2 ;

            line.setStartY(yAxis.getDisplayPosition(m * xAxis.getLowerBound() + b));
            line.setEndY(yAxis.getDisplayPosition(m * xAxis.getUpperBound() + b));

            getPlotChildren().add(line);
            lines.add(line);

            index++ ;
        }
    }


}
```

with best-fit-line.css:

```css
.best-fit-line {
    -fx-stroke-width: 2 ;
}

.best-fit-line-1 {
    -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_1 ;
}
.best-fit-line-2 {
    -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_2 ;
}
.best-fit-line-3 {
    -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_3 ;
}
.best-fit-line-4 {
    -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_4 ;
}
.best-fit-line-5 {
    -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_5 ;
}
.best-fit-line-6 {
    -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_6 ;
}
.best-fit-line-7 {
    -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_7 ;
}
.best-fit-line-8 {
    -fx-stroke: CHART_COLOR_8 ;
}
```

and a demo:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScatterPlotTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ScatterPlotWithBestFitLine plot = new ScatterPlotWithBestFitLine(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());

        plot.getData().add(createSeries("Data", new double[] {
                {10,15},
                {15,20},
                {77,77},
                {55,13},
                {44,22},
                {45,43}
        }));


        Scene scene = new Scene(plot, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Series<Number, Number> createSeries(String name, double[][] values) {
        Series<Number, Number> series = new Series<>();
        series.setName("Data");
        for (double[] point : values) {
            series.getData().add(new Data<>(point[0],point[1]));
        }
        return series ;
    }            

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You didn't really specify what you wanted to do in terms of displaying the correlation coefficient. You could create a label (or multiple labels in the case of multiple series in your plot) and add them to the chart (somewhere) in the same manner. Alternatively, you could include the correlation coefficient in the name of the series, so it appears in the legend. Using a binding between the `nameProperty()` and the data would make sure this stayed up to date if the data changes:

```
    private Series<Number, Number> createSeries(String name, double[][] values) {
        Series<Number, Number> series = new Series<>();
        ObservableList<Data<Number, Number>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            d -> new Observable[] {d.XValueProperty(), d.YValueProperty()});

        for (double[] point : values) {
            series.getData().add(new Data<>(point[0],point[1]));
        }

        series.nameProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> 
            String.format("%s (r=%.3f)", name, computeCorrelation(data)),
            data);

        return series ;
    }   

    private double computeCorrelation(List<Data<Number, Number>> data) {
        //TODO compute correlation from data...
        return 0 ;
    }
```

Comment: You're a life saver. Your code produces a line on the scatter diagram which was all i really needed - every other example was pretty bad and pretty shifty as they placed a line chart on top of a scatter diagram and changed the gradient to make one less visible which was absurd and ridiculously inefficient. I've written a method to calculate the values and have used your class just to plot the line on the calculated x and y values. It all works perfectly fine now. Thanks again :)